# Selected face texture and UV editor often disagree!

Tags: texturing, uv, faces, uv-image-editor

I have a load of 3d models which I've imported into Blender.
I'm now going through a process of replacing old textures, and it's an absolute pain to say the least.

A new texture often means manipulating the UV map. When I load a new texture for a material, when I select a corresponding face in the 3D view, the old, no longer relevant texture automatically appears in the UV window.
So I have to then select all the newly changed faces, and assign the diffuse image in the uv editor to see what I want to see!

A task made considerably more annoying when the blender file has over 2000 images, and for some reason once the image select popup is invoked, Blender goes from 60fps to <5fps until it's restarted.

The default behaviour of the UV editor seems utterly bizarre. When I select a face, it should load the first texture of the assigned material, with a quick access option to select different textures (normals, spec, etc.)

I've been struggling with this for days, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you're using Blender Internal engine.. In this case it's indeed is needed to delete one texture with all faces selected in order to get rid of its assignment (as BI uses Face Textures to show them) or you can select all after entering Edit mode and just open file with new texture. When you select a face it will open material assigned to that face and textures added to that material (choose in the list of textures which should be edited).

Comment: The problem is your unorganized project, not the Blender functionality. The way that UV Editor works is good for me, it lets you assign custom image for an actual UV mapping procedure (this images often contain some additional symbols, rulers etc), while the object uses different (final) textures in it's material. It is quite logical for me.
If you want to replace assigned texture, just select all faces in the UV editor and select new image (you can browse for an image via Open button so you don't need to wait for populating that select menu).

Comment: I guess the problem here seems to be more on your workflow's side and not on Blender's. There's nothing bizarre about the UV/Image Editor, it usually does exactly what it should. When texturing is done correctly, you usually don't select faces and assign textures to them, you work with models as a whole. Create a model, UV-unwrap it, texture it (usually by baking), there you go - one model, one texture.